# Type of join based on condition postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables, where based on type of and item in table A, I would either like to force existence in another table or not require it (in order to return this id)

I wrote the following however I am getting SQL error.

How can I achieve this behaviour?

```
    SELECT
       item.id, delivery
    FROM
       item
    (CASE 
     WHEN item.id not in (select ad_object_id from delivery) THEN 
     LEFT JOIN
       ad_object_delivery 
    ON 
       item.id = ad_object_id
    ELSE 
     JOIN
        ad_object_delivery 
     ON 
        item.id = ad_object_id
     END  
   )
```

Example data:

**item**

```
id | name   | type
1  | John   | socks
2  | Daniel | pants
3  | Barak  | shirt
```

**delivery**

```
id | item_id | delivery
1  | 1       | UK
1  | 1       | US
```

**definition**

```
id | item_id | definition
1  | 1       | UK
1  | 2       | IL
```

I would like to get as a result only John and Barak records, because Daniel appears only in delivery but not in definition. Barak appears in neither so it's ok.

Comment: What's the item condition?

Comment: I would like to return all item records if either they exist in delivery table and then the delivery field must be returned, or if they don't exist in delivery table then delivery field may not be exist.
If I only use LEFT JOIN it will return delivery empty  if they don't exist in delivery table, however, it will still return the item. if I use JOIN without left it will not return records that don't have record in delivery table

Comment: Don't understand why this is not just a left join. It will return the delivery if it exists, or a null if it doesn't exist. Maybe give some sample data to illustrate how your desired output is different.

Comment: but it will return the item record which I dont want to return at all.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I added sample data

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT i.id, COALESCE(d.delivery, aod2.delivery)
FROM item i LEFT JOIN
     delivery d
     ON i.id = d.ad_object_id LEFT JOIN
     ad_object_delivery aod2
     ON i.id = aod2.ad_object_id AND d.ad_object_id IS NULL
WHERE d.ad_object_id IS NOT NULL OR aod2.ad_object_id IS NOT NULL;
```

This matches to `ad_object_delivery` only when `delivery` does not exist.  Note that you need to adjust the `SELECT` clause to select columns from the two tables.

Comment: I updated the question - sorry, the table name for both cases is ad_object_delivery, while the column name is delivery. let me try your solution

Comment: I tried but it didn't help. it only returns to me records that exists in the delivery table. see my updated question data example

Answer (score 0):

If understand correctly you need `JOIN` with `UNION ALL` :

```
select i.id, i.name, dl.delivery
from item i inner join
     delivery dl
     on dl.item_id = i.id inner join
     definition df
     on df.item_id = i.id
union all
select i.id, i.name, null
from item i
where not exists (select 1 from delivery dl where dl.item_id = i.id) and
      not exists (select 1 from definition df where df.item_id = i.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

A confusing requirement, but I think its this:

```
select i.*
from item i
left join (select distinct item_id from delivery) del on del.item_id=i.id
left join (select distinct item_id from def) def on def.item_id=i.id
where (del.item_id is null and def.item_id is null)
or (del.item_id is not null and def.item_id is not null)
```